# AWS Beanstalk - SNS notification to Lambda when new environment gets created

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, amazon-sns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-lambda

I use a CF Template to create Beanstalk environments. I would like to trigger a Lambda code via SNS when an environment gets created so I can use the lambda to trigger a jenkins job with integration tests for the new environment.

Is there a way to send an SNS message after an env gets successfully created in Beanstalk? I already defined a topic the lambda code is subscribed to.

The beanstalk API allows you to define a notification endpoint.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.sns.html

But what is this for if I can only specify an email address and I have to confirm subscription? How can I use it to trigger an SNS message automatically?

```
      {
        "OptionName": "Notification Endpoint",
        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics",
        "Value": "no-reply@example.com"
      },
      {
        "OptionName": "Notification Protocol",
        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics",
        "Value": "email"
      },
```

A workaround I found is a bit hacky. I create an EC2 instance at the end of the stack creation process and run some AWS commands to send an SNS notification via **UserData** shell. Is this the only way?

Comment: Be aware that the JSON syntax that appears in this post does NOT agree with the syntax on the latest Amazon reference document:  (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html).  You have ("OptionName", "Namespace",  "Value"); they have ("option_name", "namespace", "value").  This seems like a ticket to insanity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question. I managed to figure out how to use SNS to trigger lambda code after a new Beanstalk env gets created.

I created an sns topic **service-configurator**

and added its ARN and name to the template.

```
    {
      "OptionName": "Notification Topic ARN",
      "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics",
      "Value": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:273218181234:service-configurator"
    },
    {
      "OptionName": "Notification Topic Name",
      "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics",
      "Value": "service-configurator"
    }
```

Next, I set the sns topic to be an event source for my lambda code.

Now, lambda gets triggered every time something happens to an environment ( instances added/removed, env created etc.)

Comment: you don't need the Notification Topic Name, the Notification Topic ARN option is sufficient.

Comment: Hi, I am having some issue using SNS. Only some of the events are reported through SNS. Some important msg like 'server restarted' never shows up.

Comment: @across I couldn't remember the details. Generally speaking, the overall structure is EBeanstalk to sns to lambda. The EBeanstalk lets you set up an email address to receive certain events, you just need to put your sns topic instead of the email.

Comment: @ChenLin yeah, the thing is it's working fine. But I'm not getting all events, but just part of them. As you mentioned "server restarted" is not working

Answer (score 1):

While [Configuring Notifications with Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.sns.html) does not provide a specific example for sending [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) notifications, `email` is simply the default for the resp. [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) option setting and you can also create subscriptions for most/all other protocols, see option [aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalksnstopics):

- **Valid Values**: `http` `https` `email` `email-json` `sqs`

Obviously [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) is not referenced there yet, but it is just another [SNS protocol](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html), so I would assume/hope that the table has simply not been updated yet and something like the following should just work accordingly (haven't tried it myself yet though):

```js
  {
    "OptionName": "Notification Endpoint",
    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics",
    "Value": "<Your Lambda function ARN>"
  },
  {
    "OptionName": "Notification Protocol",
    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics",
    "Value": "lambda"
  },
```

Comment: Afraid not! With Terraform, anyway: `ConfigurationValidationException: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'lambda' (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics', OptionName: 'Notification Protocol'): Value is not one of the allowed values: [http, https, email, email-json, sqs]`